# Include more font awesome symbols in moderncv header

Tags: symbols, moderncv, fontawesome

I would like to add the symbol `\faKey` from font awesome icons to the header of my cv, created with `moderncv`. Ideally, I would just add it like

```
\social[key]{0xBABAB928}
```

like Twitter account, but I have not found a way yet to do so.

I also tried editing the file /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesome.sty to add the \faKey command, but apparently there are more places where it would be needed to be added so I gave up this way. Having the symbol.

Introducing a line like `\faKey{0xBACAA798}` in the header near `\email` displays the symbol and text correctly, but they appear in the wrong place, above all on the top left corner of the page. So it is not an installation issue with fontawesome

Do you have an idea how I can display it under my e-mail adress?

### Minimum working example

```
\documentclass[10pt,sans,letterpaper]{moderncv}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{orange}
\moderncvicons{awesome}

\name{First}{Last}
\title{Title Here}
\email{email@example.com}
\faKey{0xBACAA798} % this leads to displaying it on top left corner of the page
\homepage{example.com}
\social[linkedin]{LinkedIn}
\social[github]{GitHub}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

### Version

I use `moderncv` version 2.0.0 and compile with pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian). Font awesome is  from 2015/07/30 v4.4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this commit to add GitLab support](https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/commit/2033517d3f29f9c16af1b3421d52f281e94aa2a5), the following code could be a workaround:

```
\documentclass[10pt,sans,letterpaper]{moderncv}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{orange}
\moderncvicons{awesome}

\name{First}{Last}
\title{Title Here}
\email{email@example.com}
\homepage{example.com}
\social[linkedin]{LinkedIn}
\social[github]{GitHub}

% define your key and add the key symbol
\collectionadd[key]{socials}{0xBACAA798}
\newcommand*{\keysocialsymbol}{{\small\faKey}~}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```